# Efficiently transform sequentially generated integer matrices into boolean matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, binary

Assume you have a list of 5 numbers, eg `L = {14, 7, 11, 14, 0};`.

Now, what you want to do with this list, is to *transform* each entry into eg a binary list, using `IntegerDigits[L, 2, 5]` and then flatten out that matrix, to get something like `BL = Flatten[IntegerDigits[L, 2, 5]]` (the last argument in `IntegerDigits` does not have to be 5, it can be anything).

`BL` is a binary list with 25 (= 5 numbers x 5 bits per entry) 0-1 entries.

What would be an *efficient* way to perform that transformation, but for a *matrix* of entries eg `M = {{14, 7, 11, 14, 0}, {1, 15, 12, 8, 15}, {3, 11, 1, 1, 5}}`.

Would the solution proposed above be similarly '*efficient*' if that process were to be repeated for a given number of times eg with 5 *different* `M` matrices (again 5 is arbitrary here)?

Please note that it is not possible to have *all* the `M` matrices available at once; it would have to be sequential.

My current implementation is this

```
BlockRandom[
   (* quick way to get 'ranges' for use in 'DiscreteUniformDistribution' *)
   ranges = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {5, 2}];

   Map[
    (* sequentially transform each matrix *)
    (Flatten /@ IntegerDigits[#, 2, 5]) &,

    (* generate 5 matrices *)
    RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[ranges], {5, 5}]
   ],

   RandomSeeding -> 123456789
 ]
```

Comment: So, `Flatten[IntegerDigits[M, 2, 5], {{1}, {2, 3}}]`?

Comment: @J.M. sure; everything else seems about right?